# Logic to use an API

Tags: vb6

I am using the MessageSave API to execute my .exe. My .exe takes the first argument from MessageSave API and does my work. When the user selects multiple messages and presses the button in the MessageSave software then the API sends multiple pings to my .exe but I want to execute my .exe when the last message is saved (meaning on the last ping). Can you please help me to write this coding logic?

**About MessageSave:** Message save is an AddIn for outlook on following url: http://www.techhit.com/messagesave/

**API Link:** http://www.techhit.com/messagesave/api.html

MessageSave does not provide any option for MultiMessages.

Comment: http://www.planetsourcecode.com/ is a good site to learn by example

Answer (score 0):

You will need to start on the first one, then the others can use one of the many forms of IPC (DDE, `SendMessage` with `WM_COPYDATA`, COM, etc) to pass the filename to the first copy.

From your description, there is no indication of first/last message so you can not get this notification.